# What are the differences between 床,　床上, and　床の上?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I think I have an idea of the differences but I'm not sure. My goal was to say "put [something] on the floor".

To me, `床{ゆか}の上` sounds the best (not that means anything). For example: `服を床の上に置きます。`

The dictionary definition of [床上{ゆかうえ}](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BA%8A%E4%B8%8A) is `建物の床の上。また、床から上。`. It looks it has more of a "above floor level" or "from the ground up" meaning, but I still see the English translation of "on a floor" (i.e. Rikaiちゃん). Is this misleading, or would something like `服を床上に置きます` work?

Lastly, where would just plain old 床{ゆか} fit into this? Does it have a connotation of the floor or a bed? Is it ambiguous if I just said `服を床に置きます`? (If so, does 床の上 not have that ambiguity?)

Bonus Credit: Have I missed anything that means "on the floor"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much difference between [床]{ゆか}に置きます and 床の上に置きます. (I think I normally say 床に置く or [下]{した}に置く in daily conversation.) 
 
I don't think you say [床上]{ゆかうえ}に置きます. I think I hear/see [床上]{ゆかうえ} in [床上浸水]{ゆかうえしんすい} or 床上まで水に[浸]{つ}かる etc. (often on TV or in the newspaper)　 
I think [床]{とこ/しょう} as "bed" is normally used in (a set phrase? like) [床]{とこ}に[就]{つ}く, [床]{とこ}に[入]{はい}る, [病床]{びょうしょう}, or [病]{やまい}の[床]{とこ}...

Comment: でも、もし畳の部屋だったら？「床に置く」じゃなくて「畳(の上)に置く」って言いそう・・・

Comment: あと、[起床]{きしょう}、死の床、[床]{とこ}の[間]{ま}、[苗床]{なえどこ}、[床屋]{とこや}・・・